# Remapping keys for single user in Registry

Tags: windows, keyboard, registry, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

## Overview:

I just have a quick question about the ability to remap keys for a single user in in the registry:

## Resources used:

ASCII table used: 
http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/theory/ascii.txt

https://superuser.com/questions/694465/remapping-a-keyboard-key-in-windows-8-1

Which pointed me towards: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/

## Attempt:

That tutorial talked about making remapping keys at the machine level via: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout

So I thought to myself what the hell I would just try the same thing under: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout

Unfortunately and somewhat expected it did not work:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /t REG_BINARY /f /d 00000000000000000400000012005b005b00A200A200120000000000
```

^^^ This was supposed to switch: ^^^

- the recognized windows key to the control key
- the recognized alt key to the windows key
- the recognized control key to the alt key

I even killed explorer.exe via power-shell:

```
taskkill.exe -im explorer.exe /f | Out-Null; start explorer.exe
```

## Questions:

- Is what I am trying to to even possible for a single user?
- If it is how would I accomplish this without third party software?

Answer (score 2):

That registry key is used by the keyboard driver.  It reads it when it starts up.  So killing Explorer has no effect, you'll have to reboot to make changes effective.  Use `shutdown.exe -r`.  Restarting the driver without a reboot is not possible.

Do beware that hacking this key is fairly dangerous, you can lose control over the machine when you make a mistake.  I recommend KeyTweak, it has let me put the Ctrl key where it belongs for the past 10 years.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it appears that the server rebooted on 2/15 and the registry edit that I made is still in place. Would Key Tweak work for a single user? I do not want to mess up the configurations for other users at work.

Comment: I see that you can save multiple configurations but that would just modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE's registry key each time with the intention of the user's of the machine being able to have different key configurations for different programs, correct?

Comment: Since it modifies the keyboard driver configuration, your changes are in effect for every user and every program.

Comment: It doesn't look like I am going to get an answer to this question since there is probably not a way to do what I am trying to do.  Thank you very much for your time in trying to help me out (I'm giving you the bounty before it expires). Please up-vote my question if you get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

For people finding this from an Internet search.

Microsoft PowerToys includes a tool for remapping keys for a user.

Probably safer than directly editing the registry.

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys
[image: PowerToys screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

If it was to work, it would hypothetically have been in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout` key in the Registry. However, in the section ["Scan code mapper for keyboards" in "Keyboard and mouse class drivers"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-class-drivers#scan-code-mapper-for-keyboards), it is noted:

> "The mappings stored in the registry work at system level and apply to all users. These mappings cannot be set to work differently depending on the current user."

so it seems impossible to do mapping this way per-user. (It is the keyboard driver that reads this setting and does the translation, not the session manager).

Answer (score 0):

1. Warnings about registry edits are meaningful, but a bit overzealous.
2. You can put registry edits into .reg files and they can be executed trivially, and a shortcut could be put almost anywhere.  You can readily make two files that toggle a specific setting.
3. Your registry is read at login.  To evince a change, log out and back into Windows.  You generally do not need to reboot.  Some of the registry is per-user, naming conventions make it pretty clear which is which.
4. This is the contents of a .reg file that makes the Menu key into a Windows key:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,5b,e0,5d,e0,00,00,00,00

5. Here is link to a document regarding composing this hexadecimal value.  I guess I plan on preserving this for myself in case this link dies.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-class-drivers
6. There are plenty of ways to map keys on a per-user basis, but I believe the registry is a dead end here.  I wonder if a combo of mapping keys to more favorable options in the registry for everyone, then setting those per-user using AuoHotkey at Startup (or something like) is the way to go.